# How can I keep track of a battle log on a web game?

Tags: javascript, rpg, databases, php, online

Recently I started working on a Web turn-based PvP RPG game. Now I'm working on the battle system but I encountered some issues:

**How can I keep track of everything that happens in the battle?** It should keep track of the characters on the field, inventory, the damage done etc.

I first thought I would simply put it in the (MySQL) database, but I think it will be too much. Especially if several people are in a battle. I thought of puting this in sessions or cookies but I don't think thats reliable.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Comment: Is this a [play-by-mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play-by-mail_game) style game?  How long do you need to store the "condition" of the battle field and how often does it change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I first thought I would simply put it in the (MySQL) database

Sounds good!

> but I think it will be too much.

Then you don't know the limits yet.

Seriously, just throw everything in a database. Don't care about performance too much at this stage, if it becomes an issue you can fix it later.

Here's an abstract view of what your database could look like:

```
Character
-- id (int, key)
-- name (string)
-- health (int)

InventoryItem
-- id (int, key)
-- character_id (int)
-- name (string)

Battle
-- id (int, key)
-- name (string)
-- location_id (int)

BattleParticipants
-- id (int, key)
-- battle_id (int)
-- character_id (int)
```

This employs something called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), where each unique piece of data is stored once and only once.

Now, if you want to get the names of the participants in a battle, you can use an inner join to combine the data tables. This should explain that:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: This is great advice, +1

Comment: Hey this is truely great advice! Luckily I know my way around with SQL! Thanks a lot!